# Soma de um produto que retorne em uma coluna o total

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, select

### Soma de um produto que retorne em uma coluna o total

Galera boa noite, gostaria de saber como posso fazer um SELECT que retorne exatamente igual o que está abaixo (modifiquei no f12 para ver se conseguem entender melhor)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

eu fiz um SELECT que está retornando o valor total, mas ele está agrupando os produtos
veja abaixo como está sendo retornado

```php
sql = SELECT *, SUM(qty_product) FROM quintada_management total GROUP BY name_product
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

como poderia resolver esse "problema"?

Comment: Você não teria que agrupar o id_m_product ao invés de name_product?

Comment: Você quer pegar todos os campos de uma linha aleatória daquele produto, dentre todas as linhas daquele produto, e ao final acrescentar a quantidade total daquele produto?

Comment: @anonimo Isso mesmo, quero somar os produtos, e crie uma coluna com o total, mas não quero que os produtos iguais se agrupem

Comment: @HeitorScalabrini eu já tentei fazer isso, mas a coluna total não retorna apenas a quantidade do produto e não soma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode, se fazer isso utilizando sub-query

```
SELECT Q.*, (SELECT SUM(qty_product) FROM quintada_management as SQ where SQ.name_product = Q.name_product) as total FROM quintada_management as Q
```

Comment: Aqui `where SQ.name_product = SQ.name_product` teve um erro de digitação, o correto é `where SQ.name_product = Q.name_product`.

Comment: Esta certo seu comentário, estou corrigindo

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi, você quer agrupar por `id_m_product` e não pelo nome do produto. Fica assim.

`sql = SELECT *, SUM(qty_product) FROM quintada_management GROUP BY id_m_product`